# how to adjust vector objects in small size with same appearance

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have little problem here.

I want to make vector icon in 16*16 pixel.

this what i face:

vector image in 600% zoom display

[image]

vector image in 100 % display

[image]

this is .png icon 16*16 is perfect display and this what I want to make

[image]

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching and found the solution.

Just go to from menu.

View -> Pixel Preview

will show me how it appears then I can adjust the design

Thanks.